# Ruby on Rails - how to parse this object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a call to a REST API and I get back a bunch of values. I am trying to figure out how to parse them.

Here are the values:

```
#<User _id: 4f8de8c40a5dcd0d1d00004c, agency_requested: [], encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FPVJDLkkD6AXd5SY/hL6KeuC6QR6vfU3OKI3oGCPxrTiEnAwvGOOu", avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_file_name: nil, agreed_to_terms: ["v1"], location: nil, last_name_first_initial: "Genadinik, A.", first_initial_last_name: "A. Genadinik", legacy_blogger_id: nil, created_at: Tue Apr 17 22:03:50 UTC 2012, active_advertiser_id: nil, avatar_source: :default, agency_roles: [], last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_sent_at: Tue Apr 17 22:03:50 UTC 2012, created_via: "CMPLY-WEB", deleted_at: nil, updated_at: Fri May 11 16:37:16 UTC 2012, last_sign_in_at: Thu May 10 20:48:53 UTC 2012, display_welcome_help: true, program_influencers: [], agency_rep: true, account_type: :influencer, legacy_user_id: nil, sign_in_count: 44, _type: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, programs: [], active_agency_id: nil, account_status: :active, admin_roles: [], legacy_password: nil, gets_newsletter: false, full_name: "Alex Genadinik", last_name: "Genadinik", reset_password_token: nil, current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", authentication_token: "ViQ5q89n39zyyVUT3wLp", user_name: "me_n0_like_scrennames", time_zone: "Chihuahua", bio: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, current_sign_in_at: Fri May 11 16:37:16 UTC 2012, confirmation_token: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, last_name_first_name: "Genadinik, Alex", agency_id: nil, first_name: "Alex", confirmed_at: Tue Apr 17 22:49:28 UTC 2012, email: "alex@cmp.ly">
```

How would a parser look like? I am pretty new to Ruby and the stuff returned is kind of difficult to make sense of, so I am not certain how/where to start.

So far I have something like:

```
  begin
    // But not sure how to loop through this stuff and extract the values.

  end
  rescue Exception => ex
    # Do something
  end
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Is the REST api actually sending back that object as a string like you have it above, or is it already an object that you are writing out with `.inspect`?  That looks to me like it's already an object and you just need to call its properties like `yourobject.encrypted_password`

Comment: @Michael actually now that I think about it, its an object.

Comment: What I need to do is to eventually massage this data so I can make a model out of it, and insert it into the database.

Comment: what data format is the API using to deliver the data?

Comment: are you using pure ruby, or is this using a framework (rails, sinatra, etc)?

Comment: Make what model out of it? Looks like it's already a `User`.

Comment: @DaveNewton the objects that are there is the LinkedIn API representation of that model. What I am trying to do is parse out the data I need and convert it into my own model.

Comment: @Awesomeness You don't need to parse anything, you have an object--you move values from one object (theirs) to another (yours), massaging as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a rails app, once you have the JSON, you can just do:

```
decoded_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)
```

decoded_json will be a hash, and you can access the values using the keys from the json, for example:

```
decoded_json["_id"]
decoded_json["location"]
```

You could also consider using something like HTTParty to deal with your communications with the RESTful API, as described here:
http://mike.bailey.net.au/2011/02/json-with-ruby-and-rails/

Comment: thanks, I have this line: Mash.from_json(get(path, headers)) ...should I replace it with my own parser to extract those values?

Comment: As far as I know, you'd only want to use from_json if the JSON object exactly matches your model.  If you need to only use some of the JSON object in the construction of your model, you would want to decode the JSON on your own and only pass the relevant keys from the JSON to your model's create/new/whatever method.